# Show python program only instead of linux gui on startup

Tags: python, node.js, linux, user-interface

Is it possible to disable linux gui rendering and any other access to the system but show only the python (or nodejs) script on startup? I want to run python or nodejs script with it's own gui on startup in the fullscreen mode and lock it but I want to hide system gui at the same time thus user can work with a python program only.
I know how to make fullscreen mode for python/nodejs gui (kiosk mode) but how to run my program and disable system gui at the same time? What linux distro is best for this task (I want to use Ubuntu)?

Comment: I think your best bet will be to install a server with no gui at all rather than disable an existing gui, which can be complicated, but possible. In any case, this question is way off-topic here, it's more suited for other places like https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same solution, with the raspbian pixel running on a raspberry Pi 3. Your situation is something similar I believe, here is what I did to come across this:

## Change /boot/cmdline.txt

*sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt*

Change the console value to
*console=tty3*

Add the following to the end of the line.

*quiet splash loglevel=0 logo.nologo vt.global_cursor_default=0*

## Tell dmesg to be quiet

*sudo nano /etc/rc.local*

Add this before 'exit 0':

dmesg --console-off #Suppress Kernel Messages

This should take care of most boot messages this far.

## Change the auto login in systemd

*sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/autologin\@.service*

Change your auto login ExecStart from:

*ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi --noclear %I $TERM*

To:

*ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --skip-login --noclear --noissue --login-options "-f pi" %I $TERM*

Make sure to change 'pi' to the username you use!

## Change /etc/pam.d/login

*sudo nano /etc/pam.d/login*

Change the line

*session    optional   pam_exec.so type=open_session stdout /bin/uname -snrvm*

To be

*session    optional   pam_exec.so type=open_session stdout*

Add .hushlogin

*touch ~/.hushlogin*

Now my boot just shows the Plymouth boot screen, and goes into my python GUI.

## Running the GUI on startup

There are multiple ways for this, but i prefer adding the program execution in /etc/profile

*sudo nano /etc/profile*

Add your python code here for execution:
Examlpe:

*sudo python /home/tkinter_gui.py*

Answer (score 0):

> I was looking for the same solution, with the raspbian pixel running on a raspberry Pi 3. Your situation is something similar I believe, here is what I did to come across this:

Thank you, it might be very helpful for me. I will test your method soon.

> this question is way off-topic here, it's more suited for other places like superuser.com

Thanks a lot. After some more searching I found interesting articles to check:

- [Kiosk tutorial for public consumption](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=521999)
- [Linux Kiosk](http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/linuxkiosk/ubuntu01.htm)

Also I found [interesting solution from Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGvFbBt-LNA) - kiosk apps for chrome os. It has cool feature out of the box that solves such task. You can simply set kiosk mode in system options so that it will run your application (your custom chrome plugin) on startup in fullscreen mode with dedicated user experience.
Furthermore, you can by chromebox for this.

Only all this was left to test. Has anyone already had experience with kiosk mode on chrome os?